# Zipping files in Python based on filename criteria

Tags: python, zip, php-ziparchive

I am fairly new to Python and I am struggling to zip files with python. The files have the same name with different extensions and I want to zip them together properly based on the names.

Basically, the files are named: "MiHPT-01.mhp", "MiHPT-01.nfo", MiHPT-01.tim", and so on. What I want is to zip each of them into an individual "MiHPT-01.zip" folder containing all of the items with the same name.

I currently tried this, however I couldn't get it to work:

```
for filename in all_files3:
    def zipFilesInDir(work_dir, filename, filter):
       # create a ZipFile object
       with ZipFile(filename, 'w') as zipObj:
           # Iterate over all the files in directory
           for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(work_dir):
               for filename in filenames:
                   if filter(filename):
                       # create complete filepath of file in directory
                       filePath = os.path.join(folderName, filename)
                       # Add file to zip
                       zipObj.write(filePath)
```

Thanks for the Help!

Comment: Did I get that edit right? You seem to be defining a function inside the for loop but not using it.

Comment: Yes, you did. I found this code on another thread and adapted to what I needed. Quite clueless why it didn't work!